# i have different responses to each answer i give. my code prints more than one response. Python

Tags: python

```
name= input ("What is your name")
print ("Greetings Master " + name)
print ("How may i be of service to you?")
gender = input ("are you a boy,or girl?")

if gender == ("boy" or "Boy"):
  print ("Greetings Mr" + name)
if gender == ("girl" or "Girl"):
  print ("Greetings M'lady " + name)

print ("which of these games do you like most?")
game = input ("Rainbow 6 siege, Skyrim, Halo, Undertale")

if game == "Rainbow six siege" or "rainbow 6 siege":
  print ("I see you like tactical shooters")


if game == "Skyrim" or "skyrim":
  print ("Greetings, Dovahkiin.")

if game == "Halo" or "halo":
  print ("Sci-Fi is the best!")

if game == "Undertale" or "undertale":
  print ("I see, you truly love a great story")
```

The part where it you are supposed to type what game you like is supposed to respond with one response like "I like sci-fi".
this is the response i get.

```
What is your nameJax
Greetings Master Jax
How may i be of service to you?
are you a boy,or girl?boy
Greetings MrJax
which of these games do you like most?
Rainbow 6 siege, Skyrim, Halo, Undertaleskyrim
I see you like tactical shooters
Greetings, Dovahkiin.
Sci-Fi is the best!
I see, you truly love a great story
```

As you can see, i printed Skyrim as my favourite game but it also printed the response that i would have recieved if i was to type "rainbow six siege".
Please help.

Comment: And why do you believe `game == "Undertale" or "undertale"` will inspect whether `game` is one of them? Python interprets it as: `(game == "Undertale") or "undertale"` (and `"undertale"` is considered to be `True`). You need to write: `game in ('Undertale','undertale')`...

Comment: I did the change and now it does not respond any of the responses

Comment: please edit your question with the new code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the most probable bug in your code. Here `game` is compared only with `Rainbow six siege`. The condition after `or` is always `True` and hence all the if statements become `True`. In your case, no matter what you `game` you enter, it will execute all the `print` statements.

```
>>> game = "Hello"
>>> if game == "Rainbow six siege" or "rainbow 6 siege":
...    print "I am printed"
...
I am printed
```

I would highly recommend using `in` instead of `== and or` together while checking for conditions. Below code will help you achieve what you want.

```
name= input ("What is your name")
print ("Greetings Master " + name)
print ("How may i be of service to you?")
gender = input ("are you a boy,or girl?")

if gender in ("boy", "Boy"): 
  print ("Greetings Mr" + name)
if gender in ("girl", "Girl"):
  print ("Greetings M'lady " + name)

print ("which of these games do you like most?")
game = input ("Rainbow 6 siege, Skyrim, Halo, Undertale")

if game in ("Rainbow six siege", "rainbow 6 siege"):
  print ("I see you like tactical shooters")

if game in ("Skyrim", "skyrim"):
  print ("Greetings, Dovahkiin.")

if game in ("Halo", "halo"):
  print ("Sci-Fi is the best!")

if game in ("Undertale", "undertale"):
  print ("I see, you truly love a great story")
```